# British for "one-trick pony"

Tags: british-english

I've been told that a "one-trick pony" is an American saying. What is the British equivalent for it?

Comment: Just in case there is any doubt, while one-trick pony may have a US origin, though no-one has verified that as yet, it is perfectly understood and widely used in British English. No-one would be confused by it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider the following, which looks at the issue from a different perspective: instead of saying it can *only* do one thing, this speaks about wanting to do *more* than just one thing.

> **have another/more than one string to your bow**
>   *uk*
>   to have more than one interest, skill, or resource that you can use if you need to:
>   *I enjoy my work, but I'd like to have another string to my bow in case I lose my job.*
>   [- Cambridge Dictionary](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/have-another-more-than-one-string-to-your-bow)

Comment: And this can be used as in: **They only have one string in their bow.**

Answer (score 0):

Aside from one-hit wonder, I grew up believing the phrase is equivalent to:

> [Jack-in-the-box](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jack-in-the-box)

It was invented by an Englishman, [Sir John Schorne](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/John_Schorne), and really is a 'one trick pony' in that after you've seen it once, there is little fascination with the toy left.

Comment: I've never heard jack-in-the-box refer to anything other than the toy or to someone who can't sit still. Can you give an example of it use that shows equivalence to one-trick pony?